# How do I stop my little brother from throwing things?

Tags: behavior, safety, pre-teen

My brother is usually very nice to me, but sometimes he acts out. I can't be harsh with him because he is not a mature. He gets in a habit of throwing things.

What can I do to get him to stop throwing things?

Comment: Is your brother already a pre-teen? Are you acting *in loco parentis*?

Comment: yes he is..sometime i act like that

Comment: Does he do that for a reason (e. g. when he is angry)? Does he, for example, appear to be angry when he does that or seems to find it funny?

Comment: he did this in both conditions

Comment: Hi Intesar, welcome to the site.  I took a pass at improving the language, please let me know if you don't agree with any part of it.

Comment: no sir i am agreed but i want soloution to this problem

Comment: How old is your brother?  And how old are you?  And what do your parents do when your brother throws things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Help him figure out why he throws things. Maybe he does that instead of hitting people, harming himself, etc.
2. Forget about the throwing itself and help him address the feelings that cause the throwing.
3. Offer an alternative to throwing things, like going for a long run together. Or, find a safer way for him to throw things — buy a couple baseball gloves and have a catch with him.
4. Find out if he sees agrees with you that his throwing things is a behavior that should change. Maybe he continues because he doesn't see it as a problem.
5. Realize that you might not be equipped to change his behavior all by yourself. If your parents or another more experienced adult is available, enlist their help.
6. Try not to take his behavior personally.